# How to use same foreign key multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I have a movie, the movie can have one or two Gender.
The Gender come from another table.

Laravel trow this two errors(aparently the second relation won't create an object relation to take the gender title)

> ErrorException in fdc637007ae29076d303671b0f7f6c5282ce835a.php line
>   42: Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   C:\laragon\www\testeAtlas\testeAtlas2019\resources\views\pages\show-movie.blade.php)
>
> ErrorException in fdc637007ae29076d303671b0f7f6c5282ce835a.php line
>   42: Trying to get property of non-object

Migrates:
movie table creation

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('gender_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('gender_id')->references('id')->on('genders');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->integer('year')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

movie added second gender option

```
Schema::table('movies', function ($table) {
            $table->integer('secondgender_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('secondgender_id')->references('id')->on('genders');
        });
```

Gender Table

```
Schema::create('genders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Models:
Movie Model

```
class Movie extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function gender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Gender');
    } 

    public function secondGender()
    {

        // dd("inicio");
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Gender');
    } 

    //protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

Gender Model

```
class Gender extends Model
{
    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Movie', 'gender_id', 'secondgender_id');
    }
}
```

View:

```
                        {{-- Call the first gender --}}
                        <span> Genêro: {{ $movie->gender->title }}</span>

                        {{-- If movie have an second Gender... --}}
                        @if ($movie->secondgender_id)
                           <br>
                           <span> Genêro Secundário: {{ $movie->secondGender->title }}</span>
                        <br>
                        @endif                   
                        <span> Duração: {{ $movie->lenght }} min.</span>
```

If the movie have two gender call the second too;

Something like "Toy Stroy" -Animation and -Adventure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of you writing `secondGender()` as relationship name, Laravel expects the column to be called `second_gender_id`. As your column is called `secondgender_id`, you simply need to pass this different name as second parameter to your relationship definition:

```
public function secondGender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gender', 'secondgender_id');
}
```

My recommendation is to always pass all arguments to relationship definitions because it makes them more explicit and it does not hide Laravel magic. It also helps new developers to come on bord faster because it is more obvious what is happening. In other words, I would even pass the third parameter (key column of the foreign table):

```
public function secondGender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gender', 'secondgender_id', 'id');
}
```